# Change Password issues in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Hi i'm trying to changing the password so the user's password is update on the database. For example, i want the user Mary Tan's password to be changed from 12345 to 54321. But if affect the rest of the user's password. I really idk how to fix it.

Output:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYvpv.jpg)

Table
[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG4su.jpg)

My Code:

```
protected void btnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = null;

            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LeaveManagementCS"].ConnectionString;

            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            string sql = "UPDATE Staff Set Password=@NewPwd";

            if (Session["Username"] != null)
            { 
                sql += " WHERE UserName='" + Session["Username"].ToString() + "'";
            }

            string newPwd = tbNewPassword.Text;

            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPwd", tbNewPassword.Text);

                conn.Open();

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    if ((tbNewPassword.Text == dr["newPwd"].ToString()))
                    {

                    }
                }

                dr.Close();


                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if(rows > 0)
                {
                    lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    lblOutput.Text = "Password has been changed successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lblOutput.Text = "Password does not match with our database records.";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = "Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: check Session["Username"] , I think this condition is false

Comment: Session["Username"] is null. Most likely. Verify if there is a value for this.

Comment: This code has the potential for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @AshwinNair : is it? How can we avoid them?

Comment: Parameterized queries or Stored Procs.

Answer (score 0):

Which means your `Session["Username"]` is `null` at this moment of execution. Hence the Where condition will skip and update all rows. And What is the Function of Reader There? It is not necessary, The [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) is enough to do this Job and it will  returns the number of rows affected. So you can do this in the following way:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LeaveManagementCS"].ConnectionString;
if (Session["Username"] != null)
{
    string sql = "UPDATE Staff Set Password=@NewPwd  WHERE UserName=@Username";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPwd", tbNewPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["Username"]);
            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows > 0)
            {
                lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                lblOutput.Text = "Password has been changed successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblOutput.Text = "Password does not match with our database records.";
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{ 
  // Show message that Session is Empty Can't Proceed
}
```

**Important Note** :- Don't save password as plain Text, [Hash and salt them](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this (check Session in the start)

```
protected void btnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Session["Username"] == null)
        {
             //User is not logged-in. Display message or handle
             return;
        }
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LeaveManagementCS"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = "UPDATE Staff Set Password=@NewPwd Where UserName = @UserName";

        string newPwd = tbNewPassword.Text;

        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPwd", tbNewPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Session["Username"].ToString());

            conn.Open();

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if ((tbNewPassword.Text == dr["newPwd"].ToString()))
                {

                }
            }

            dr.Close();


            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (rows > 0)
            {
                lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                lblOutput.Text = "Password has been changed successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblOutput.Text = "Password does not match with our database records.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "Error Message: " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Glad if it helped you.

Comment: What is the purpose of `cmd.ExecuteReader();` here